# How to align a Mach-Zehnder at 810 nm?

Tags: optics, photons, interference, interferometry, light-emitting-diodes

I have a task to arrange MZI using very weak source with photons coming one at a time. On top the wavelength is 810 nm. How to 'see' the interference pattern  to 100% in one channel and 0% in other. I have a CCD and suppose to let it integrate over a big interval of time. I heard about plates which can multiply the number of photons? But do they work at 810 nm? I can use piezoelectric motor too.

Comment: do you have any ways to crank up the light power. That would ease the alignment process. If you have enough light power, there are some infrared viewing cards (https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=296). If this does not works, you can replace your light source with an alignment laser.

Comment: Can a red laser be used to align MZI and than replace the laser with the weak 810 nm source?

Comment: I would say yes. But this strongly depends on your experimental setup.

Answer (score 0):

You really can't beat a deep depletion CCD here. A photocathode will have poor quantum efficiency. Mutiplying a fraction of the photons, while throwing out the majority of them, will only hurt your signal to noise ratio. Look for a CCD with good NIR quantum efficiency.

Comment: Is it bad idea to use photo paper as in old times instead CCD?

Comment: @Mercury Photo paper has low quantum efficiency. It would require a *much* longer exposure, perhaps by a factor of 1000.